# Google Workflows: Args header seems to be "headers"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

From https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax#invoking_an_http_endpoint

```
call: {http.get|http.post|http.request}
    args:
        url: URL_VALUE
        [method: REQUEST_METHOD]
        [header:
            KEY:VALUE
            ...]
```

It states that to pass the headers the yaml element is called "header".
This did not work for me, you get error:

```
unexpected entry 'header'
```

When using "headers", it seems to work correctly.

From https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/getting-support it suggests using the tag "google-workflows".
I could not tag this entry with "google-workflows" as suggested; since the tag doe not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this error with our documentation.

Indeed you are correct, "headers" seems to be the correct way to utilize this argument when invoking HTTP endpoints via the Workflows API.

I have submitted this issue internally in order to investigate the related [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax#invoking_an_http_endpoint) accordingly.

Please note that this product is [in beta](https://cloud.google.com/products), and therefore issues like this are expected during this time.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks. It was not anything serious, just wanted to let you know. 
I would have logged it as an issue, but the link on https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests
does not seem to work.

Comment: This indeed seems odd, thank you for reporting this, I have submitted a internal investigation for [this section](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests) of our public documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use that syntax is with `headers` is like this:

```
- shortenUrl:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten
        headers:
            Authorization: "Bearer <token>"
            Content-type: "application/json"
        body:
            domain: bit.ly
            long_url: https://cloud.google.com/blog
```

Comment: yes, thanks. That is what I tried to say in the post.
The documentation from https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax#invoking_an_http_endpoint says use "header". But it is suppose to say "headers" I believe.